# A non-recursive, explicit formula for the Fabius function

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions, sequences-and-series

The [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) $F\colon\mathbb R\to[-1,1]$ may be defined as the unique solution of the functional integral equation 
$F(x)=\int_0^{2x}F(t)\,dt$ for all real $x$ such that $F(1)=1$.

The [recent MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350989/conjectured-formula-for-the-fabius-function) provided a link to the [MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283519/conjectured-formula-for-the-fabius-function), asking to confirm a conjectured "non-recursive, self-contained formula for the Fabius function". The MO post has been overall negatively received and may get closed. I think the mentioned MathSE question may be of interest.

On this page, whereas the mentioned conjectured formula will not be confirmed so far, a simpler non-recursive, explicit formula for the Fabius function will be offered, which is expressed in terms similar to, but simpler than, those in the conjectured formula.

So, a question yet remains: Can one use the simpler formula [below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/351005) to confirm the conjecture on MathSE? Or maybe one could do that otherwise?

Comment: Is there a question, or is this just a way to provide a place to put [your answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/351005)?

Comment: @LSpice : Indeed, I may have to think of a better way to present the MathSE question.

Comment: @LSpice : Now I have an explicit question.

Answer (score 8):

As noted in the linked Wikipedia article on the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function), on the interval $I:=[0,1]$ the Fabius function coincides with the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of 
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}U_j,$$
where the $U_j$'s are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $I$. So, for each $x\in I$ 
$$F(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x),\tag{1}$$
where $F_n$ is the cdf of $\sum_{j=1}^n 2^{-j}U_j$.

Next (see e.g. [formula (2.2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06406v1)), for any real $x$
$\newcommand\vp{\varepsilon}$
\begin{equation}
 F_n(x)=\text{vol}_n(I^n\cap H_{n;c^{(n)},x})
 =\frac1{n!\prod_1^n c_i}\,\sum_{\vp\in\{0,1\}^n}(-1)^{|\vp|}\,
 \big(x-c^{(n)}\cdot\vp\big)_+^n,  
\end{equation}
where $\text{vol}_n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$, $H_{n;b,x}:=\{v\in\mathbb R^n\colon b\cdot v\le x\}$, $c^{(n)}:=(c_1,\dots,c_n)$, $c_j:=2^{-j}$, $|\vp|:=\vp_1+\dots+\vp_n$, $\cdot$ denotes the dot product, and $t_+^n:=\max(0,t)^n$. So, for $x\in I$
\begin{equation}
 F_n(x)=\frac{2^{n(n+1)/2}}{n!}\,\sum_{y\in D_{n,x}}(-1)^{s(y)}\,
 \big(x-y\big)^n, \tag{2} 
\end{equation}
where $D_{n,x}$ is the set of all dyadic numbers in $[0,x]$ of the form $m2^{-n}$ for integers $m$, and $s(y)$ is the sum of the binary digits of $y$.

Formulas (1) and (2) provide the answer to the question.

---

Some of the differences between (1)--(2) and the formula conjectured in the linked MathSE post are as follows:

- In the MathSE post, the main conjectured formula for $F(x)$ is stated only for dyadic numbers $x$, and then extended to all values of $x$ by the continuity of $F$.
- The expression in that post for $F(x)$ for dyadic $x$ contains a double summation and a number of $q$-Pochhammer symbols (I have had no experience with those symbols).

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this formula terminates at a finite sum for dyadic x, or perhaps it doesn't. This seemed to be one of the goals of the original MathSE post.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "this formula terminates". Anyhow, the sum in (2) is over a finite set.

Comment: I mean that this approach takes in a value x in I and produces a sequence of numbers which converge to F(x). However, if x is a dyadic rational then F(x) is known to be rational, and it is not clear if the sequence of values that this method produces will return that value exactly after a finite number of steps. I think this would be a desirable quality of a "solution" to the problem of finding a fast approximation to F(x).

Comment: @GregZitelli : This sequence is strictly increasing for each $x$ in  $(0,1)$.